# Best way to calculate max jobs run simultaneously

Tags: c#, algorithm, reporting

I have to create report calculating max jobs count ran at the same time, based on start time and end time.

So for example I might have such data:

```
var jobs = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("10:30") },
    new { Id = 2, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:20"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("11:00") },
    new { Id = 3, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:40"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("10:50") },
    new { Id = 4, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("11:10"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("11:30") },
};
```

So max count should be 2, because 'overlapping' jobs are only 1&2 and 2&3

What would be best approach to analyse that ?

Comment: You want to know how many are running simultaneously?

Comment: For a better solution transform start/end into individual events amounting to an increment / decrement in resources. Sort the collection of all events, and then compute the global maximum over the series. That will also continue to work if jobs amount to more than "1", and also gets you ideal runtime complexity for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the periods like this picture:

```
09:50 
10:00 |
10:10 |
10:20 | |
10:30 | |
10:40   | |
10:50   | |
11:00   |
11:10       |
11:20       |
11:30       |
11:40
```

Imagine you move horizontal line throw this picture. You can use the counter that increments when the line crosses the start of a period, and decrements when the line crosses the end. Max value of the counter is the result that you need.

We need prepare data to implement the algorithm.

```cs
var points = new List<(TimeSpan, bool)>();
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    points.Add(job.Start, true);
    points.Add(job.End, false);
}

points = points.OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
               .ToList();
```

Now we can count max of vertical lines.

```cs
int count = 0;
int max = 0;

foreach (var point in points)
{
    if (point.Item2)
    {
        count++;
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
    }
    else
        count--;
}
```

Comment: I didnt analyse carefully your algo - but (correct me id Im wrong) your approach is to show max jobs count in predefined time slots (eg every 10 mins) while I need exact figures with presision to eg milisec

Comment: @Maciej, the algo works with any time periods. I've got 10-minutes data from your question just to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

Seems straight forward. This works for me:

```
var jobs = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("10:30") },
    new { Id = 2, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:20"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("11:00") },
    new { Id = 3, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("10:40"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("10:50") },
    new { Id = 4, Start = TimeSpan.Parse("11:10"), End = TimeSpan.Parse("11:30") },
};

var events =
    from j in jobs
    from e in new []
    {
        new { Timestamp = j.Start, Value = 1, },
        new { Timestamp = j.End, Value = -1, },
    }
    orderby e.Timestamp, e.Value
    select e.Value;
    
int a = 0;
int max = 0;
foreach (var e in events)
{
    a += e;
    max = max > a ? max : a;
}
```

I get `2`.

Now, it can slight be improved with Microsoft's `System.Interactive` NuGet library.

```
int max = events.Scan(0, (a, x) => a + x).Max();
```

Comment: @Ext3h - This is exactly computing how many did overlap at once. Why don't you think it does?

Comment: @Ext3h - You should then make sure your question covers every case, rather than popping up exceptions after the fact.

Comment: @Ext3h - When I add it `10:31-10:39` I get `3` which is what I would expect. Can you explain how it's wrong?

Comment: @Ext3h - And without `ID == 2` I get `0` which is what I'd expect.

Comment: @Ext3h - Yes, I've done that. Perhaps the question isn't clearly stated?

Comment: @Ext3h - AH, it took me a while to catch that. I've updated the answer.